# Missing Libraries make no sense

Tags: library, osx

I've never much issue importing a library to my master sketchbook location, restarting Arduino, then using the library examples. Today is a different story:

1. I'm loading [RCLib](https://github.com/jantje/ArduinoLibraries/tree/master/RCLib) which is part of this [ArduinoLibraries](https://github.com/jantje/ArduinoLibraries) family
2. RCLib requires [PinChangeInt](https://github.com/GreyGnome/PinChangeInt)

So everything is in my sketchbook location right? `Arduino > Preferences > Sketchbook Location`

Still I'm getting compiler errors about missing libraries:

```
/Users/Jackson/Documents/Arduino/ArduinoLibraries-master/RCLib/Examples/Maga6ChanelsA8_A13/Maga6ChanelsA8_A13.ino:7:86: fatal error: PinChangeInt.h: No such file or directory
 #include "PinChangeInt.h"
```

I've even tried `#include <PinChangeInt.h>` Which makes more sense since this is a system library.

**What is going on here?**

The sketch I'm trying to run:

```
/**This is an example of using the RCLib with a mega and pinchangeint
 * This example isprovided as is by Jantje
 * Congratualtions, constructive feedback and I like it can be send to eclipse@baeyens.it
 **/

#define NUM_RC_CHANNELS 6 //You need to specify how many pins you want to use
#include "PinChangeInt.h"  //If you need pinchangeint you need to include this header
const uint8_t RC_Channel_Pin[NUM_RC_CHANNELS]={
  A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,A13};//Here I specify I want to listen to pins A8 to A13 of my mega

uint16_t RC_Channel_Value[NUM_RC_CHANNELS]; //This variable will contain the values read from the RC signal
#include "RCLib.h" //This include needs all declarations above. Do not try to move it up or it won't compile
```

*Arduino v1.6.9 | OSX 10.11.4*

Comment: The libraries should be in *sketchbook location* -> `libraries`. Try using `#include <PinChangeInt.h>` (note the less-than / greater-than).

Answer (score 2):

I had downloaded PinChangeInterrupt through Arduino

Sketch > Include Library > Manage Libraries... > *Filter your search...* > PinChangeInterrupt > Install

I thought this is all I needed but I was wrong. This differs from the popular [PinChangeInt library](https://github.com/GreyGnome/PinChangeInt). Ultimately the file names where slightly different which is why my file was showing as missing. I found this out by manually looking at the file names in the library I was trying to used and comparing them against my includes.